# Bigquery Error code: Window ORDER BY expression references column start_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery for SQL and I can't figure out why there is an error message that comes like this:

```
Window ORDER BY expression references column start_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:73]
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM start_date) as week, count(start_date) as count,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY start_station_name ORDER BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM start_date))
from `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
GROUP BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM start_date), start_station_name)
```

I thought I have grouped the week below, as seen in the last line. So what can cause this error message to keep popping up?

Comment: The query you pasted should not be generating this error AFAIK.  Are you certain that this is the actual code you ran?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387124/can-stack-overflow-do-any-more-to-promote-the-asking-of-better-questions-by-new

Comment: @Tim, yes that is the code I ran.

Answer (score 4):

This is a parsing error in BigQuery, which you can work around with an aggregation function.  Your query has another issue, which is the `start_station_name`.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM start_date) as week, start_station_name, count(start_date) as count,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY start_station_name ORDER BY MIN(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM start_date)))
from `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

The `MIN()` really serves no purpose other than lettering BigQuery parse the query.  Because the expression is part of the `GROUP BY`, there is only one value for the `MIN()` to consider.

This is a bug in the BigQuery parsing, because it does not recognize that the expression is the same as the expression in the `GROUP BY`.  Happily, it is easy to work around.

Comment: what is the logic of order by(min(..))? Oh and thanks for the help, I will try it later.

Comment: Wow! This has been plaguing me for years and such a simple solution!!

Answer (score 1):

try like below using cte

```
  with cte as
    (
    SELECT *, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM start_date) as week

    from `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`

    ) select week,count(start_date) as count,
     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY start_station_name ORDER BY week)
     from cte group by week,start_station_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In query you need to make sure that you have to put ORDER BY only on those values which you are selecting.

With your query, the problem is you are doing ORDER BY EXTRACT(WEEK from start_date). Rather than doing this you should write ORDER BY week because you are selecting week already